# Ikfastdemo Does Not Compile

Tags: ros, ikfast, openrave, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to create a fast inverse kinematics solver using OpenRAVE's ikfast, following the tutorial here:
http://ros.org/wiki/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_Fast_IK_Solution

All is well until I get to step 6. When I try to compile the demo, I get the following error message:

```
/tmp/cctZjKHD.o: In function `IKSolver::solvedialyticpoly12qep(double const*, double*, int&)':
ikfastdemo.cpp:(.text._ZN8IKSolver22solvedialyticpoly12qepEPKdPdRi[IKSolver::solvedialyticpoly12qep(double const*, double*, int&)]+0x296): undefined reference to `dgetrf_'
ikfastdemo.cpp:(.text._ZN8IKSolver22solvedialyticpoly12qepEPKdPdRi[IKSolver::solvedialyticpoly12qep(double const*, double*, int&)]+0x626): undefined reference to `dgetrs_'
ikfastdemo.cpp:(.text._ZN8IKSolver22solvedialyticpoly12qepEPKdPdRi[IKSolver::solvedialyticpoly12qep(double const*, double*, int&)]+0x6e8): undefined reference to `dgeev_'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using ROS Furte, OpenRAVE 0.8.2, and sympy 0.7.0 as in the tutorial.

Anyone have any ideas or run into similar problems?

**Edit 1:**

Commands entered, as reconstructed from my .bash_history and memory:

```
cd ~/ros/dev_stacks/cwru-ros-pkg/cwru_abby/abby_description/urdf/
rosrun collada_urdf urdf_to_collada abby.urdf abby.dae
cd ~/openRAVE #openRAVE 0.8.2 root directory
export collada_file="/home/ed/ros/dev_stacks/cwru-ros-pkg/cwru_abby/abby_description/urdf/abby.dae" #path to collada file
openrave-robot.py $collada_file --info links
python ./python/ikfast.py --robot=$collada_file --iktype=transform6d --baselink=32 --eelink=39 --savefile=output_ikfast61.cpp
wget http://kaist-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/arm_kinematics_tools/src/ikfastdemo/ikfastdemo.cpp
vim ikfastdemo.cpp #Edit includes to point to correct cpp file
cp python/ikfast.h . #Copy ikfast header file into this directory
g++ -lstdc++ -llapack -o compute ikfastdemo.cpp -lrt
```

**Edit 2:**

Code can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/4662558

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53542/ikfastdemo-does-not-compile/) by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1185 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on 2013-01-28**:
A quick Google search for "dgeev" refers to LAPACK.  You should post the exact commands you're typing into console, and if you can link to your copy of the demo code and the output from IKFast, people can check if you have configured it properly, and try to compile it themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Modifying the order of the arguments to g++ solved my problem:

```
g++ ikfastdemo.cpp -lstdc++ -llapack -o compute -lrt
```

I've edited the tutorial on the wiki accordingly.

---

Originally posted by [Ed Venator](https://answers.ros.org/users/2636/ed-venator/) with karma: 1185 on 2013-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1